# How to properly use Particle Systems in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, particle-system

So I have been trying to figure out how to use **Particle Systems** in Corona SDK.
I've tried reading up on it and I got as far as *emitters*, but was stuck from there. How do you connect the Particle System and the emitter together?

```
function NewTrail()
ParticleSystem:createParticle(
    {
        flags = { "wall" },
        x = display.contentCenterX,
        y = display.contentCenterY,
        velocityX = 100,
        velocityY = 0,
        color = { 0, 0, 1, 1 },
        lifetime = 32.0
    }
)
end
timer.performWithDelay( 100, NewTrail, -1 )

-----------------------emitter---------------------------

local emitterParams = {
    textureFileName = "particle.png",
}
local emitter = display.newEmitter( emitterParams )
```

Okay so after this didn't work I thought maybe Particle Systems and emitters are two different things so I tried this:

```
local emitterParams = {
    textureFileName = "images/particle.png",
    duration = -1,
    speed = 100,
    particleLifespan = 5,
    maxParticles = 20,
    angle = 180,
    startParticleSize = 10,
    finishParticleSize = 0,
}
local Trail = display.newEmitter( emitterParams )
Trail:start()
```

And it still didn't work. Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally figured it out. I still don't understand emitters so if someone would like to help with that please do. To get a Particle System to work you have to first start Physics which is:

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()
```

and then initialize a Particle System by doing:

```
local testParticleSystem = physics.newParticleSystem(
  {
  filename = "images/particle.png",
  radius = 3,
  imageRadius = 4
  }
)
```

Finally you have to create the actual particles which is done like so:

```
local function onTimer( event )

    testParticleSystem:createParticle(
      {
         flags = "water",
         velocityX = 256,
         velocityY = 480,
         color = { 1, 0, 0.1, 1 },
         x = 0,
         y = 0,
         lifetime = 32.0
      }
    )
    end

timer.performWithDelay( 20, onTimer, 0 )
```